# How do I delete a user account from my PlayStation 3?

Tags: ps3

I don't see any obvious option to delete a user account and corresponding PSN data from my PS3. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Log in as the user whom you want to delete. Select the icon of the user, press the <kbd>Δ</kbd> [triangle] button, and then select [Delete] from the options menu"

<sup>[Source](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/users/deleteuser.html)</sup>

Comment: What if I can't log on as that user? Is that possible?

Comment: No, just the current user can be deleted.

Comment: So that means, if someone creates an account on my PS3, and sets a password, then I can't get it removed ever?

Comment: @McKay well, you can delete the user, but if you don't know the PSN password you can't deactivate the account of your system, but the user can certainly be deleted.