# How do I delete the main PSN account on a PlayStation 3 without the password?

Tags: ps3, psn

When I got my PlayStation 3, I used a school email address to make my PSN account.

I didn’t use my PlayStation 3 for a couple of years because I thought it had the red light of death. When I realised it still worked, and started using it again, I couldn’t remember the password for my PSN account. I can’t reset the password, because I don't have access to my school email address anymore.

Is there any way to get rid of the main PSN account? It seems to be a bit of a problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a user account from my PlayStation 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/109217/how-do-i-delete-a-user-account-from-my-playstation-3)

Comment: @Lemon: There seems to be a diffrence between a PSN account and a user account. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114322/changing-psn-log-in-on-one-user may provide some help, but not a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the password, what I personally would do is just leave the account on the system and just forget it's there.   Just make a new account and add it to the ps3, as you can have more then one account at a time on a ps3.   So just make a new account and not worry about the old one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to terminate an SIE account without access to the account itself.

Contacting PlayStation support also wouldn't help because you have no way to verify that you own those accounts.